# jQuery traversing (finding right CSS selector), and alternating background-color

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-selectors

I want to find the right CSS or jQuery selector to edit the `background-color`, which is defined inline. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="rev_slider_3_1">
    <ul style="Something">
       <li style="Something">
           <div class="slotholder">
               <div class="tp-bgimg" style="background-color: for example blue"></div>
           </div>
       </li>
       <li style="Something">
           <div class="slotholder">
               <div  class="tp-bgimg" style="background-color: for example red"></div>
           </div>
       </li>
       ...(A few more li's)
     </ul>
</div>
```

It would be really nice if someone could tell me the correct CSS or jQuery selector to change the `background-color` of the `<div>` **individually** where I want to alternate what the `background-color` is.

Because it's a plugin I can't change the HTML of course.

```
$("The Css Selector I'm searching for").css("background-color")
```

**UPDATE:**

I want to change the .`tp-bgimg` background color, but there are more than one `.tp-bgimg` and they need to get different `background-color`s so I want to have a jQuery selector that lets me individually change for example the first `.tp-bgimg` `background-color`. I need the colors to alternate.

Comment: which div's color you want to change.?

Comment: you want different colors for each `div` in an `li`? How are you deciding what `div` gets what color?

Comment: I want to change the .tp-bgimg background color...

but there are more than one .tp-bgimg and they need to get different background-colors

Comment: @iD4ve You can use `array` and `.index()` to get your concept working.

Comment: Since your question is *actually* about a special jQuery plugin, you ought to ask a new question which references the answer here, and goes specifically into that special plugin. The question you asked is answered. Now you have a new question: "How do I get alternate background-color to work with X plugin"

Comment: I don't think that it has something to do with the plugin...

because the background of the slides change if I manually set another background value via my browser... so if your script would work It would do what I want

Comment: And by the way, I see it working. And I see where it is failing. I will update my answer one more time.

Answer (score 4):

To get control on each `div` alone it's better to use [jQuery .each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). So you can use code like this:

```
$('.tp-bgimg').each(function(i,e){// i==>is the index of element, e==> the element itself
    $(e).css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

***Update:***

If you want to give each `div` a new color then we have 2 solutions:

1. Generate random color in every loop inside `each` assign to each .tp-bgimg color.==> ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zBu9B/)***
2. Have a predefined set of colors as array of colors and again in every loop assign to each `.tp-bgimg` color but here you need to to know how many `.tp-bgimg` you have so you could have the correct corresponding number of colors. ==> ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zBu9B/1/)***

Comment: It's basically the same than the one before but this does not solve my problem

Comment: @iD4ve can you please update your question and explain what you exactly want ot do?

Comment: 2. would apply to my problem...

And I know how many divs I have because its a slider

Comment: @iD4ve check that **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zBu9B/1/)**. i made it as if you have 4 slides

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to use `$(".tp-bgimg")` but not just that. You also seem to want this:

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Fixed and made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/C4UK3

So, then go one by one through the elements like this, and modify each one as needed:

```
$( document ).ready( function() { 
    var colors = [ "#f00", "#00f", "#0f0" ]
    var i = 0
    $(".tp-bgimg").each(function() {
        if( i >= colors.length ) {
            i = 0
        }
        $(this).css("background-color", colors[i++])
        console.log( colors[i] )
    });
})
```

As you will see, I added code for alternating background colors as you like.

See:

[image: alternating colors]

Comment: That does not really what I want ...

I want to change the div's background-color of the first tp-bgimg for example to red and the 2nd to blue and so on...

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Comment: This seems to be a good idea, but it somehow doesn't work....

Comment: Everything works now. Check out the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.... it somehow doesn't work ...

You seem to miss some semicolons?

Comment: I have it working in the fiddle. Did you look at the fiddle?

Comment: Yes I did but in my case it does not work...

Can I send you the URL privately somehow?

Comment: Sure, you send it at http://digitalextremist.com

Comment: I have sent you the Url

Comment: It is working for me... But you mix #hex and english color names. blue is `#00f` for example/ That doesn't seem to be the issue though. Remove the `alert("HELLO")` line and try that.

Comment: Put it up in `tpj(document).ready(function() {})`

Comment: still not working sorry...

Comment: It is working perfectly for me after the last changes you made.

Comment: what is tpj(document).ready() ?

Comment: tpl(document).ready() must be added by the WP plugin. It is a duplicate of jQuery(document).ready(). Where you have it is fine though. I see the issue you are looking at.

Comment: In all browsers still white Background behind "Hoellen Design" although blue is assigned via your script...

Comment: This goes beyond the question. Now the problem is the the elements are changed extensively by the plugin, and their order is changed, etc. So far I've proven the answer is correct and this is now a new question.

Comment: I see that your answer should fix the problem...
But this won't help me...

The order of the LI's does not change

Answer (score 1):

[**jquery :eq() selector**](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)  will fit your needs.

Example:

```
$('li:eq(0) .tp-bgimg').css('background-color','blue');
```

Will change the bgcolor of the div `.tp-bgimg` in the *first* `li` element ( the first is indexed 0 the second 1 and so on)

This way you can change color of a li individually but you have to know whether it's the first, second etc.

**UPDATE**

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LVAUD/) to show you how you can change them individually and with different colors.

Comment: This seems better but I don't want to change the background-color of slotholder... but the background-color of .tp-bgimg

Comment: @iD4ve: Fixed the class, my fault :) and I've linked you an example, if you want to check

Comment: Can I send you the webpage privately somehow ... so you can see where my error is?

Comment: sending it here is fine too. So others can help